# Kurento Android onLocalSdpOfferGenerated is not triggered

Tags: android, webrtc, kurento, peer

The callback `onLocalSdpOfferGenerated` is not get triggered after when offer generated `nbmWebRTCPeer.generateOffer("local", true);`.

Why this call back is not get triggered ?

I have already asked question with complete code in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258756/android-client-for-kurento-room) but i didn't get any answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by commenting log in the callback function

```
//Log.d("onLclSdpOfrGen","******** localSdpOffer : "+localSdpOffer.description+" connection : "+connection.getConnectionId());
```

but still i cant establish peer connection. here i am following tutorial http://doc-webrtcpeer-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/DevelopersGuide.html

```
@Override
public void onLocalSdpOfferGenerated(SessionDescription localSdpOffer, NBMPeerConnection connection) {


//Log.d("onLclSdpOfrGen","******** localSdpOffer : "+localSdpOffer.description+" connection : "+connection.getConnectionId());

if (!isMyVideoPublished) {

    kurentoRoomAPI.sendPublishVideo(localSdpOffer.description,false,129);

    //String username = "qwerty";
    //kurentoRoomAPI.sendReceiveVideoFrom(username, "webcam", localSdpOffer.description, 129);

    isMyVideoPublished = true;
}else {

    String username = "qwerty";
    kurentoRoomAPI.sendReceiveVideoFrom(username, "webcam", localSdpOffer.description, 129);

}
}
```